# "Failed to prune session" and "Error: self-signed certificate" in nodejs app on render.com

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, session, express-session

A nodejs app using `express`, `express-session`, and `connect-pg-simple` to create user sessions and send httpOnly cookies back to the client.

Session options configured this way (`getEnv` is just a wrapper around `process.env`):

```
import pgConnect from 'connect-pg-simple';
import session, { SessionOptions } from 'express-session';

const PgStoreGenerator = pgConnect(session);

const sessionStore = new PgStoreGenerator({
  conString: getEnv('DATABASE_URL'),
  tableName: 'user_sessions',
  createTableIfMissing: true,
});

const sessionOptions: SessionOptions = {
  store: sessionStore,
  name: getEnv('SESSION_NAME'),
  secret: getEnv('SESSION_SECRET')!,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    secure: true,
    httpOnly: true,
    maxAge: +getEnv('SESSION_MAXAGE')! * 1000,
    sameSite: 'none',
  },
};
```

A setup like this worked before on railway.app, but when I moved to render.com, user sessions don't work, having 2 main error situations:

1. `connect-pg-simple` will try to prune expired sessions from the database regularly, but I'm seeing these in the logs:

```bash
Apr 26 11:17:13 PM  Failed to prune sessions: self-signed certificate
```

2. when actually trying to create the session and sending the cookie, this is the log:

```bash
Apr 26 11:18:05 PM  Error: self-signed certificate
Apr 26 11:18:05 PM      at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1540:34)
Apr 26 11:18:05 PM      at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
Apr 26 11:18:05 PM      at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:959:8)
Apr 26 11:18:05 PM      at ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:743:12)
```

I can provide more code if needed, but the app is created the usual express way, and the setup works correctly in localhost when in fact using a dummy self-signed certificate from  the `mkcert` package:

```
import { Express } from 'express';
import https from 'https';
import { server } from '#/api/server.js';
import { getEnv } from '#/utils/get-env.util.js';

const PORT = process.env.PORT || getEnv('PORT');
const IS_LOCALHOST = getEnv('NODE_ENV') === 'localhost';
let app: Express | https.Server;

if (IS_LOCALHOST) {
  const mkcert = await import('mkcert');
  const validityDays = 365;
  const ca = await mkcert.createCA({
    organization: 'localhost',
    countryCode: 'LH',
    state: 'localhost',
    locality: 'localhost',
    validityDays,
  });
  const tls = await mkcert.createCert({
    domains: ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost'],
    validityDays,
    caKey: ca.key,
    caCert: ca.cert,
  });
  const { key, cert } = tls;

  app = https.createServer({ key, cert }, server);
} else {
  console.log('prod');
  app = server;
}

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`server up @${PORT}`));
```

EDIT: I'm receiving this error when using render.com; app is a Web Service in there, and, [according ot their docs](https://render.com/docs/tls), all services come with TLS certificates from Let's Encrypt, and all http requests are redirected to https, so I'm not sure it's a problem there (I've opened a community question there, as well).